# jquery mobile .on not working on page load, only after refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This function only works after I refresh the page on jquery mobile.. any ideas?

```
$('.item').on('touchstart pageinit', function(){
```

I am trying to make something clickable that toggles a classs.. ie: a button.  Only works after refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('touchstart pageinit', '.item', function(){
```

Comment: I also have similar issue, I have this button on click method inside on pageinit, but it only works after refresh. Wondering can you help me... here's my code: `$(document).on("pageinit", function() { $("#closebutton").on("click", function() {......});  });`